# Decoding array buffer leads to different results than decoding text

Tags: javascript

I had written some example JavaScript that fetches a non-UTF-8 file that was shown to me by someone that I am trying to help. I have only the textual data, not an ArrayBuffer of their file.
Upon viewing the text file using simple UTF-8 encoding, it becomes obvious that the text is not UTF-8 or UTF-16 character encoding, it is actually GBK.

Now, upon using the ArrayBuffer, I get a readable text from the string.

Yet, the text should be equivalent to the ArrayBuffer data, so, if I use the text, as I had done afterward, the result should be the same, but this is not the case.

Can anyone explain this?

The code:

```js
// non_UTF_8_Blob: Blob
const non_UTF_8_Blob = await (
    await fetch(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdutwsl/Testtxt/main/not-utf8-test.txt", {
            mode: "cors"
        }
    )
).blob(); // yes, I *could* just use Body#arrayBuffer, but I didn't

// non_UTF_8: ArrayBuffer
const non_UTF_8 = await non_UTF_8_Blob.arrayBuffer();

// text: string
const text = await non_UTF_8_Blob.text();

// buffer_from_text: ArrayBuffer; should be equivalent to non_UTF_8, right?
const buffer_from_text = new TextEncoder().encode(text);

// properly_decoded_text: string; I thought this would be correct, but it's actually still nonsense
const properly_decoded_text = new TextDecoder("GBK").decode(buffer_from_text);

console.log(text); // original nonsense string

// result of decoding the file's ArrayBuffer
const UTF_8 = new TextDecoder("GBK").decode(non_UTF_8);

console.log(
    "when used on an array buffer, becomes:\n%s\nwhen used on a string, becomes:\n%s",
    UTF_8, // properly decoded text
    properly_decoded_text // nonsense
);
```

An edited version of this is hosted [here](https://decode.xxperthacker.repl.co/index.xhtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding and encoding text is not lossless if the data that got decoded can not be mapped by the encoding table.

The `text` variable holds a string that represents the tentative to read `non_UTF_8` as UTF-8. Characters that don't map between both encodings will thus get read incorrectly and result in invalid characters.

```js
const data = new Uint8Array( [ 210, 254, 203, 189 ] ); // 隐私 in GBK

const read_as_UTF8 = new TextDecoder().decode( data );
console.log( "read as utf-8", read_as_UTF8 );
console.log( "first characters are same?", read_as_UTF8[ 0 ] === read_as_UTF8[ 1 ] );
```

The original bytes values have been lost now, `read_as_UTF8` contains two Replacement Characters and an other non-sense one.
Using a *TextEncoder* on this will generate a new ArrayBuffer representing this *read_as_UTF8* text: `��˽`, and this text's byte dump is not the original `[ 210, 254, 203, 189 ]` but

```
[
  239, 191, 189, // �
  239, 191, 189, // �
  203, 189       // ˽
]
```

```js
const data = new Uint8Array( [ 210, 254, 203, 189 ] ); // 隐私 in GBK

const read_as_UTF8 = new TextDecoder().decode( data );
const utf8_as_arrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode( read_as_UTF8 );
console.log( [ ...utf8_as_arrayBuffer ] );
```

I hope you can now appreciate why your `properly_decoded_text` variable actually doesn't hold *properly decoded text* at all.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that the encodings are simply not lossless.
Ahh, I see it now. I had thought that the replacement character (?) was only displayed by the font if it didn't support that code point, but I see that the actual character was replaced with it. Guess I misunderstood how this worked. Thank you. Now to put this newfound knowledge to use.

Comment: When a font doesn't have a glyph, an other font will be used, if no such font exists, then a special system font is used (generally it results in an empty rect, or a rect with the codepoint written in it). That replacement character means there was an issue while decoding the data.

Comment: Do you have any references that I could look into myself, so that I may learn how invalid code points are dealt with and such?